# Anatlytics - Two trackingIDs, only one get events

Tags: google-analytics

we have two tracking codes on our site. On both codes we get tracking of visitors and stuff correct, but when it comes to events, only one is getting the event even tho' we're sending it to both codes.

This is the setup:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-6', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-123456-4', 'auto', 'clientTracker');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('clientTracker.require','displayfeatures'); 
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('clientTracker.require','ecommerce','ecommerce.js'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

and this is the event:

```
$("#desktopCheckout").on("click", function() {
      ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'clickOnCheckout');
      ga('clientTracker.send', 'event', 'test', 'clickOnCheckout');
});
```

The event is being sent to the regular tracking code, but not to the "clientTracker".

Are we doing something wrong here?

GA Debug extension and Tag assistant extension in Chrome both shows that the event is being sent, and I've checked the tracking ID so it is correct. Just somehow Google Analytics is not recieving this.

Comment: Have you checked your view filters for the second account ? If this is sent then the problem is probably not on the client side.

Comment: This is completely correct! We had filters that blocked out my events. Thanks!